# only fields are allowed in a $sort mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-2.0, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to do get nearest records like below but the sort operation complained to expressions not allowed. How can achieve this in MongoDB?

#### Error:

> **NotSupportedException: Only fields are allowed in a $sort.**
> *MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateOrderBy(OrderByExpression
> node)*

#### Code:

```
public virtual List<Post> PagingNearest(Expression<Func<Post, bool>> predicate, int offset, int limit, GeoCoordinatePortable.GeoCoordinate coord)
{
    return _context.Posts.AsQueryable()
             .Where(predicate)
             .OrderBy(x => x.Location.GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo(coord))
             .Skip(offset)
             .Take(limit)
             .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to query a number of documents that contain GeoJSON coordinates, and sort them according to distance from a particular point?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by casting it to a list, then sorting and in my case once again casting the returned IOrderedEnumerable to a list.

The last case .ToList() is of course optional, it just suited my needs.

In my case I'm also ordering by a boolean value with a ternary operator.

`.ToList().OrderBy(e => e.SomeBoolean ? 0 : 1).ToList();`

Comment: Note: If you do this you are sorting on the server instead of in the database. If you're doing any sort of Skip/Take this won't work.