# MongoDB: only fields are allowed in a $sort error, while only fields are used in the sort

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting, asp.net-core

This is my first time using MongoDB. I'm using it in an ASP.Net Core project. this is my code:

```
collection.AsQueryable()
.OrderByDescending(u => u.created_at)
.Skip((page - 1) * perPage)
.Take(perPage)
.ToList();
```

I'm getting the following error in the controller with no clue in the stack trace:

> only fields are allowed in a $sort

[only fields are allowed in a $sort mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095761/only-fields-are-allowed-in-a-sort-mongodb) suggests using `.ToList()` before sorting. although it works, I don't want just to load the whole table and do the sort in the server.

[IQueryable complex order Only fields are allowed in a $sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458387/iqueryable-complex-order-only-fields-are-allowed-in-a-sort) doesn't apply to me as I'm just using a field to sort.

what is wrong with my Linq query that MongoDB doesn't like?

Comment: what type of property is created_at? is it a calculated field or unmapped field? if yes, then mongo it's unable to do in-memory queries

Comment: @DragosStoica it's a `DateTime`

Comment: is it a mapped field? could you also post the model and the mongo mapping?